# Can we pass 'recordId' to a flow using apex trigger code?

Tags: apex

'recordId' is a flow variable.
I am not able to use this subflow thats why trying with apex trigger.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your original question and include these details.

Answer (score 1):

So long as `recordId` is an input variable (this is a setting you can toggle on the Flow) you can call the flow from Apex and pass a value to `recordId`. See the example below. Replace `.myFlow` with the API name of your flow.

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
params.put('recordId', someId);
params.put('someVariable', true);

Flow.Interview.myFlow myFlow = new Flow.Interview.myFlow(params);
myFlow.start();
```

*EDIT*: One additional consideration is that Apex Triggers are bulkified, so similarly, you may need to make your Flow bulkified to deal with situations when multiple records are updated. Unfortunately, the documentation on calling Flows from Apex is geared towards controllers and not triggers. Take a look at the answer here for some ideas: [How to bulkify Flow call from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271376/how-to-bulkify-flow-call-from-apex)

Comment: N.B. - params are case sensitive